# How to make a function(x) accept x as a column name?

Tags: r, function

I have the following setup:

mydata:

```
  today_date
r1  11.11.21
r2  11.11.21
r3  11.11.21
```

I want to convert column like 'today_date' to a date using

```
as.Date(today_date,tryFormats = c("%d.%m.%Y")).
```

So I'm using the following function, which is supposed to change the corresponding column to proper dates:

```
myfun <- function(x){
  x<- as.Date(x,  tryFormats = c("%d.%m.%Y"))
}
```

In this function x is representing a variable corresponding to: mydata$today_date
Sadly, x is properly representing the object that's to be replaced, so instead of:

```
myfun(mydata$today_date)
```

I still have to use:

```
mydata$today_date<- myfun(mydata$today_date)
```

How can I manipulate the function so the as.Date()-functionality is directly applied? I'm pretty certain that the variable in myfun(x) is not properly able to represent the subsection of my dataframe that I want to change. Any help is very welcome!

Comment: Almost everything in R is passed by value. No reference/pointer passing, therefore the the second option is the best option you have. Unless of course you want to be super complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this.

```
df <- data.frame(today_date = c("11.11.21","11.11.21","11.11.21"))

myfun <- function(df, var = 'today_date'){
  df[[var]] <- as.Date(df[[var]],  tryFormats = c("%d.%m.%Y"))
  return(df)
}
```

The output is

```
> myfun(df, "today_date")
  today_date
1 0021-11-11
2 0021-11-11
3 0021-11-11
```

Comment: This still is exactly the same as what OP has. There is no change within the original dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I like the magrittr assignment pipe syntax for this.

```
library(magrittr)
mydata$today_date %<>% myfun()
```

Instead of `mydata$today_date<- myfun(mydata$today_date)`

Comment: Thank you this was really helpful! :)